# Simplest way to detect if any model value has changed

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I'm using [gorm](http://gorm.io/) as a Golang ORM. I need to detect if any model field has changed to trigger a update on a thirdy-party API service.

I have tried to test every field with an If statement, but it gets ugly when the model has many fields.

```
var person Person

db.Where("id = ?", id).First(&person)

if person.Name != body.Person.Name || person.Age != body.Person.Age {
  // Trigger API update
}

db.Save(&person)
```

Is there a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the simplest way, and [it is probably not idiomatic](https://go-proverbs.github.io/), but you can accomplish this with reflection. The following function uses the [reflect Package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) to compare two `Person` structs to see if their values for each field are the same, skipping the `Model` struct (whose internals vary independently of the data element the `Person` represents).

```golang
func (this Person) Equals(that Person) bool {
    vThis := reflect.ValueOf(this)
    vThat := reflect.ValueOf(that)
    for i := 0; i < vThis.NumField(); i++ {
        if vThis.Field(i) != vThis.FieldByName("Model") {
            if vThis.Field(i).Interface() != vThat.Field(i).Interface() {
                return false
            }
        }       
    }
    return true
}
```

You could use this in your code snippet then as follows:

```golang
if !person.Equals(body.Person) {
  // Trigger API update
}
```

Note that I'm quite new to go, so I may be leading you astray here in terms of "proper" code. But this does work.

Answer (score 1):

GORM does provide such a feature via the 'Changed' method which could be used in Before Update Hooks. It returns if the field was changed or not.

https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Check-Field-has-changed